# Replace appended data with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that when a user submits values, the jquery script I have calculates the form values and outputs the calculated data.

This works fine except if a user clicks on the submit button again it appends my lopped  data to the existing data (which is duplicated or new data is re-appended).

If the user clicks submit twice I just want it to overwrite the existing looped output.

```
  for (i = 1; i <= $jumps; i++) {

        if (i == 1) {
            var $num = $jumpSize * i;
        } else if (i == 2) {
            var $num = ($jumpSize * i) + $stops;
        } else {
            var $num = ($jumpSize * i) + ((i - 1) * $stops);
        }

        $('.output').append("<p>Num:" + i + " " + parseInt($num) + "</p>");

    }
```

Is it possible to replace the looped data if the users hits the submit button twice.

Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/knard/EY8MJ/13/

Comment: empty the element before you append. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before loop add this line `$('.output').html("");` So it will clear contents, when submit button is pressed. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EY8MJ/14/

Comment: Thanks that did it! After two days of trying to resolve this, that does the trick. I knew it was something simple. This in essence clears the content on submit.

Answer (score 2):

Use .html instead of .append to replace the content. For example...

```
$('.output').html("<p>Num:" + i + " " + parseInt($num) + "</p>");
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie I tried this method already and while it does replace the old value and doesn't allow for the loop data to output, but I thought it should've have as well.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced he same problem. here is how I solved it. Lets Say you are expecting a new response everytime a request is made with ajax

```
      $.ajax({
        url: "scanner/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf,
            'barnumber': $("#search-input").val(),
            'id':id
             },
             
        success: function (res) {
            const data = res.data
            console.log(data)
            $('student-result').html("");
            data.forEach(e=>$('#student-result').html(`
             <tbody >
                <tr>
                  <td>Name:</td>
                  <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">
                    ${e.lname} 
                    ${e.fname}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              
              </tbody>

            `));
        
    });
```

Points to note. Instead of using ***.append*** method to render the data use ***.html*** which renders directly to the element id replacing it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.output').empty().append("<p>Num:" + i + " " + parseInt($num) + "</p>");
```